# Ordered Lists - Double Letters

Tags: html, html-lists

This might be a simple question but it is eluding me right now.

I have an ordered list and it is extending past the A-Z and is going into the double letters, which is fine.  The double letters come out in this format:

AA. AB. AC.

and was wondering if there is a way to make them come out as:

AA. BB. CC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible in native HTML as the spec defines that it goes `...X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC...`. There may be some javascript method of creating the listing yourself though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs over at Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type):

> The CSS specification does not define how alphabetic systems wrap at
>   the end of the alphabet. For instance, after 26 list items,
>   upper-alpha rendering is undefined. Firefox and other browsers will
>   continue as AA, AB, AC,... For long lists, it is recommended that
>   authors specify true numbers.